# Dash transparency doesn't look right

Tags: unity, unity-dash, 13.04, transparency

Well, I don't know what words to express this problem but here's the picture..

[image]

as you can see, there is a problem with the background opacity of unity...

how to solve this?? I'm using the april 21 daily build image and updated the system since the release of 13.04.... I'm using an HP mini laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this a blur problem.
Install Unity Tweak Manager.
Choose Unity - Search.
You should change Background Blur from OFF to ON.

Comment: thank you very much! however, it is already turned on. so I turned it off. it looks much better now. thank you!